# How to add loader in the left of the text using css

Tags: html, css, loader

I created a loader with text but it did not fit with the text, I have also attached the screenshot for your reference.

My html:

```
var html = `<div class="messages warning">
    <h2>Network Drive Sync In Process....</h2>
    <blockquote>"Please do not close or refresh this window during process</blockquote>
    </div>`
jQuery("#block-system-main").html(html);
```

CSS:

```
.messages.warning {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 )
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif')
    no-repeat;
}

.messages.warning {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.messages.warning {
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

I want to adjust loader in the centre of the text in left-hand side, currently, you can see it's at the top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need `background-position:left center;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background as your spinner gif you can put it as img.
Then you can use this css:

```
.messages.warning {
 display:    none;
 position:   relative;
 height:     50%;
 width:      50%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Or leave it as is and add the

```
background-position: center left;
```